# exec('curl url') function not working from php (Laravel) application

Tags: php, laravel, curl, exec, php-curl

I am using Laravel 5 for our development.

I have such structure:

- trigger page http://localhost/some/random/url:

code inside:

```
exec("curl http://localhost/public/action/test");
```

- http://localhost/action/{param} page:

  code inside:

  `$rand = rand(1, 5); 
  sleep($rand); 
  Storage::append('result.txt', 'Time: ' . time() . '; Rand: ' . $rand . "; RowId: " . $id); 
  return 'Time: ' . time() . '; Rand: ' . $rand . "; RowId: " . $id;`

if I run this command in cmd `curl http://localhost/public/action/test`, everything works fine, result.txt file is created and I got response from return statement. If I try to run from application with exec() from http://localhost/some/random/url, seems "action/{param} page" is not executing at all.

P.S.
Why I am not using `curl_exec()`, because I try to make something similar to multi threading, because as I know that `exec()` executes in another process, but `curl_exec()` not.

P.S.S.
Why I am not using pthread library, because it not possible to switch our project to 7.2 php version.

Comment: What indicates to you, that the command is not running? Can you provide the return value or potential errors of `exec()`? Do you receive anything on WARNING or NOTICE level when executing the PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use curl this way.
Use CURL without `exec`:
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

You are using composer, so you could also use https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle